# Show that the equation $Ax=b$ is not consistent for all possible $b$, and describe the set of all $b$ for which the equation is consistent

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that the equation $Ax=b$ is not consistent for all possible $b$, and describe the set of all $b$ for which the equation is consistent, both algebraically and geometrically.

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1& 3& -4\\
-2& 1& 2\\
3 &2& -6
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$b = \begin{bmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\b_3\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE!  Please consider taking the time to familiarise yourself with the [faq] to learn some of the common practices here.  In addition, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) should help you learn how to typeset mathematics.  Also, as this question appears to be homework, please consider reading [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question) to help you ask effective homework-related questions.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Set up the augmented matrix,

$$\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1&3&-4&b_1\\
-2&1&2&b_2\\
3&2&-6&b_3
\end{array}\right]\;,$$

and do a row reduction. The numbers have been chosen to make it very easy.

Comment: I have done row reduction to get: 1 0 14 = b1-3(b2+2b1), 0 1 -6 = b2+2b1, 0, 0, 0 = b3-3b1+b2+2b1. (Sorry, still learning MathJax). It seems that the third column contains free variables?
$
( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 14 \\
0 & 1 & -6 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \end{array})
$

Comment: @Faeynrir: It does, but that’s not the real point here. I get $$\begin{bmatrix}1&3&-4&b_1\\0&7&-6&b_2+2b_1\\0&0&0&b_3+b_2-b_1\end{bmatrix}$$ In order for this to be consistent, $b_3+b_2-b_1$ has to be $0$, since that last line corresponds to the equation $0x_1+0x_2+0x_3=b_3+b_2-b_1$.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. So, the algebraic description of the solution set where A is consistent is simply where $0x_1+0x_2+0x_3 = b_3+b_2-1b_1$; I'll have to think a bit about the geometric description.

Comment: @Faeynrir: Here’s a hint: what does the graph of $z+y-x=0$ look like?

Comment: It's a plane with part of the plane following / covering x=0. So, geometrically, the solution set here is similar, but following $b_3+b_2-b_1=0$?

Comment: @Faeynrir: You’ve got it. It’s that plane through the origin.

Comment: Thanks so much! This was a great help.